# Jquery .valid() method causes form to display highlighted fields on load

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I wrote a script that should only run on submit if the form is valid. Basically the user fills out a form from a tab and then if the form is valid, the script runs and unhides the next tab and automatically navigates the user to it. Here is the script:

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
    if ($('#quoteform').valid() == true) {
                    $('#submitbutton').click(function () {                
                        unhidetab();
                        $tabs.tabs('select', 2);
                        return false;               
                    });
                }
```

The script functions as needed, but there's a problem. On page load, it automatically highlights the fields as invalid. Is there a way to write this so that it still functions but doesn't automatically highlight required fields as invalid on page load? Thanks.

Comment: Where is this script located? what's his context?

Comment: It's in an MVC3 application. Unfortunately I had to remove jquery-validate.min and jquery-unobtrusive-validate.min because for some reason they cause errors within the program and I can't figure out why. I'm going to have to use a completely different approach now I guess.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was the jquery script that we were referencing.

Comment: Post your own reply to the question and accept it then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you sholud bind the script to the submit button, otherwise it's executed when it's launched (on document.ready() i suppose)

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function (event) {                
   if ($('#quoteform').valid() === true) {
      //submit the form or do what you want
   }else{
      event.preventDefault();//avoid submitting the form 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want **validate** field only submit page?
If yes, I think you need change your script:

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

$('#submitbutton').click(function () {                
    if ($('#quoteform').valid() == true) {
        unhidetab();
        $tabs.tabs('select', 2);
        return false;               
    } 
});
```

// Sorry for my english, I'm brazilian.

Comment: Hey Patrick, I actually tried moving the if statement within the click function before but assumed it wasn't working. I think there might be something else within my program that's messing it up though since you also say to move it. Let me go check a few things. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove your function from jQuery onLoad event: **$(document).ready(function() { ...**
2. move it new one **function validateMyForm() { ...**
3. activate that function when a user changes form fields:

> ```
> <input type="text" onkeyup="validateMyForm()" onblur"validateMyForm()">
> ```

Comment: can you specify where it is stated then?, if it is not included in **named function** it will run during page load

Answer (score 0):

Update: There was an issue with the jquery script we were referencing.